# Load Balancing & Windows Failover Cluster 2008 r2

Tags: failovercluster, windows-cluster

I have a windows service that I would like to load balance and failover. I have had a quick play with the failover cluster manager and it seems I can only have one active node with n inactive failovers. Is there a way to have two active load balanced nodes and two inactive load balanced nodes to failover to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Windows Server Enterprise, yes.
You would cluster 2 pairs of machines that each run NLB.

Comment: So run nlb over the top of cluster and failover feature? I then lose my ability to use a single virtual IP from the consumers?